# Postfix to Dovecot connection was interupted, where did Postfix store my email?

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I upgraded my postfix and dovecot mail server, turns out I forgot to configure delivery from postfix to dovecot. Postfix instead delivered the email itself(according to the logs as it's says "delivered"). The problem is I can't seem to find  *where* Postfix stored the email for my users.

Can someone point me to the location(s) where postfix might have delivered it?

Comment: Post the `postconf -n` output and maillog lines when postfix get email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It depends on the address classes of your domain. That's why I ask `postconf -n` output and some maillog lines*).

There are [four address classes](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html) in postfix, two of them has capabilities to deliver it directly to mailbox: local domain class and virtual mailbox domain class.

If your domain listed on `mydestination` parameter, then it falls into **local domain class**. You should inspect parameter [`home_mailbox`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#home_mailbox) and [`mail_spool_directory`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mail_spool_directory) to determine where the postfix save file. Below was snippet of [man 8 local](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html).

> **MAILBOX DELIVERY**
>
> > The default per-user mailbox is a file in the UNIX mail spool directory
> >        (**/var/mail/**user or **/var/spool/mail/**user); the location can be specified
> >        with the **mail_spool_directory** configuration parameter. Specify  a  name
> >        ending in / for qmail-compatible maildir delivery.
> >
> > Alternatively,  the  per-user  mailbox can be a file in the user's home
> >        directory with a name  specified  via  the  **home_mailbox**  configuration
> >        parameter. Specify a relative path name. Specify a name ending in / for
> >        qmail-compatible maildir delivery.

Otherwise if your domain listed on `virtual_mailbox_domains` parameter, then it falls into **virtual mailbox domain class**. You should inspect the value of [`virtual_mailbox_base`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_base) and [`virtual_mailbox_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_maps) value of specific recipient. virtual(8) delivery agent lookup the location of mailbox based on those parameters. Parameter $virtual_mailbox_base is unconditionally prepended to $virtual_mailbox_maps result, so the absolute path of email storage is `$virtual_mailbox_base$virtual_mailbox_maps`. See also [man 8 virtual](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.8.html).